# Bind android emulator to a specific network adapter

Tags: android, network-adapter, emulator

I have 2 network interfaces on my Windows machine. 1 is my main WAN router, and the other is a modem with limited data cap. I have 2 problems I want to solve:

1. I want my Android emulator (googles android emulator) to be connected through the modem
2. As I said, the modem has a data cap, so if possible, I want to ensure that no other program uses it to access internet

I tried [ForceBindIP](https://r1ch.net/projects/forcebindip) (`ForceBindIP 192.168.0.xyz "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\emulator.exe" -avd AVD_NAME`), but I could still access my router and NAS server in the android emulator, which I should not be able to.

How can I achieve my goals?

Comment: If you are a private user you may want to check out the Android emulator provided by Genymotion. These emulators base on Virtualbox and therefore allow a much more fine granulated network access using the standard VirtualBox network adapter and configuration system.

Comment: @Robert, I already have VirtualBox running. Will the two come in conflict with each other?

Comment: Genymotion just uses the existing VirtualBox and adds the emulated device as new virtual machine. Therefore I would not expect any conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry it's not very precise (I'm on Linux right now), but, if I recall correctly, you should be able to achieve that thanks to the Windows firewall services, through the **Windows Firewall Advanced Security MMC snap-in**.

I'm not sure if you have shortcuts available and if it's available on non-professional editions of Windows, but if it's available you should get it by launching mmc directly :

1. Launch the Microsoft Management Console from a command line by typing `mmc`
2. Bring the snap-in loading modal window : go to the **File** menu and choose **Add/Remove snap-in...**
3. Choose the **Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security** snap-in : select it, click the **Add** button and click **OK**

You can then create rules authorizing or denying outbound access through interfaces based on various criteria, including authorizing a given program.

Changes are immediate, and don't require closing MMC.

If the snap-in doesn't appear in the registered snap-ins list, then it probably means your edition of Windows doesn't include it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want me to set static IP for both my network interfaces. Then, create custom rules to block all inbound and outbound connections on the local IP on my modem to all programs. And then create a rule to allow the emulator access through the modem. Did I get this right? (I don't have much experience with the firewall)

Comment: So I created a custom rule to block all connections on local IP 192.168.0.xyz (the network interface the modem's connected to), and above that I created a rule to allow all connections for cmd.exe, yet when I try to ping google I get General failure. What do I do now?

Comment: Ah sorry, I'm not on Windows but I will have a check tomorrow french time (UTC+2) if you didn't sort it out in the meantime. The order of the rules is important indeed. Maybe you should better allow the emulator program instead of `cmd.exe`... I'm not sure blocking inbound traffic is really necessary since it's what the firewall does by default anyway, so only focus on the outbound rules, as a start...

Comment: Moreover, I don't think using a static IP address is really necessary, you should be able to apply a rule to an interface, independently of what its address is.

Comment: Thnaks, I'll look into it more 